# Can't update database with EF Core AddRange

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am getting the following error with the code below:

- I am declaring my repository with AddScoped in my restful api when I use this. Still does not work. (services.AddScoped<ICampRepository, CampRepository>();)
- I have tried using AsNoTracking(), but SaveChanges does not work. Even when I tell EF that the state has change, I get the same error all over again.

**The instance of entity type 'ConferenceRoom' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.**

```
        public async Task<bool> AddRangeTalksAsync(List<Talk> talksToBulkInsert, string moniker)
        {
            try
            {
                IQueryable<Camp> query = _context.Camps.Where(c => c.Moniker == moniker);

                Camp camp = await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync();

                camp.Talks.AddRange(talksToBulkInsert);

                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Below is a sample of list of objects that I am trying to insert. One works, but any more than one does not work.

```
[
   {
      "id": 0,
      "campId": 0,
      "title": "Talk for 'CompuGen Core Code Camp #4' for conference room 'Conference Room #1' for day 1 hour 1",
      "abstract": "This talk is interesting, you will like it.",
      "level": 1,
      "food": "Bread",
      "beverage": "Water",
      "swag": "Talk T-Shirt and a notebook",
      "startTime": "2022-01-03T08:00:00",
      "endTime": "2022-01-03T09:00:00",
      "conferenceRoom": {
         "id": 307,
         "campId": 34,
         "conferenceRoomName": "Conference Room #1",
         "conferenceRoomCapacity": 56
      },
      "talkSpeakers": [],
      "talkAttendees": [],
      "ratings": []
   },
{
      "id": 0,
      "campId": 0,
      "title": "Talk for 'CompuGen Core Code Camp #4' for conference room 'Conference Room #1' for day 1 hour 2",
      "abstract": "This talk is interesting, you will like it.",
      "level": 1,
      "food": "Bread",
      "beverage": "Water",
      "swag": "Talk T-Shirt and a notebook",
      "startTime": "2022-01-03T08:00:00",
      "endTime": "2022-01-03T09:00:00",
      "conferenceRoom": {
         "id": 307,
         "campId": 34,
         "conferenceRoomName": "Conference Room #1",
         "conferenceRoomCapacity": 56
      },
      "talkSpeakers": [],
      "talkAttendees": [],
      "ratings": []
   }
]
```

Also, the database schema looks like this from the entities I created in EF CORE.

[image: Database Schema for the Core Code Camp Conference Scheduling System]

What I am looking for, is to how to keep this schema intact, and be able to create multiple conference rooms for a Camp in one go, but this does not work.

Comment: The way you have done this is too complicated, it could be simpler. Are you trying to create a new conference room when you create talk or just add a conference room 307 that already exists?

Comment: Just trying to create a collection of conference rooms added to a camp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I think I have this fixed for now. What I did was to change the way the Talks table was created. For the ConferenceRooms Foreign Key, I have the following for onDelete: ***onDelete: ReferentialAction.NoAction***. So this will remove the circular reference between ***ConferenceRoomId*** and ***ConferenceRoom***. However, if the ConferenceRoom is deleted, the related talk will not be deleted. This might be undesirable, but I can delete the this data using another method, if needed.

My new Talk Definition:

```
public class Talk
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor for Talk.
        /// </summary>
        public Talk()
        {
            Ratings = new List<Rating>();
            TalkSpeakers = new List<TalkSpeaker>();
            TalkAttendees = new List<TalkAttendee>();
        }

#pragma warning disable 1591 //Ingore compiler warning for not having XML comments.

        [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
        public int CampId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Navigation property to a Camp.
        /// </summary>
        public Camp Camp { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Navigation property to ratings.
        /// </summary>
        public List<Rating> Ratings { get; set; }

        public int ConferenceRoomId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Navigation property to a Conference Room.
        /// </summary>
        public ConferenceRoom ConferenceRoom { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Abstract { get; set; }
        public int? Level { get; set; }
        public string Food { get; set; }
        public string Beverage { get; set; }
        public string SWAG { get; set; }
        public DateTime startTime { get; set; } = DateTime.MinValue;
        public DateTime endTime { get; set; } = DateTime.MinValue;

        /// <summary>
        /// TalkSpeaker joins Talk and Speaker together.
        /// </summary>
        public List<TalkSpeaker> TalkSpeakers { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// TalkAttendee joins Talk and Attendee together.
        /// </summary>
        public List<TalkAttendee> TalkAttendees { get; set; }

#pragma warning restore 1591

    }
```

Changing the Foreign Key on ConferenceRooms so there is not a circular reference between ***ConferenceRoomId*** and ***ConferenceRoom***.

```
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Talks",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    CampId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    ConferenceRoomId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    Title = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    Abstract = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    Level = table.Column<int>(nullable: true),
                    Food = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    Beverage = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    SWAG = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    startTime = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                    endTime = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Talks", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Talks_Camps_CampId",
                        column: x => x.CampId,
                        principalTable: "Camps",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Talks_ConferenceRooms_ConferenceRoomId",
                        column: x => x.ConferenceRoomId,
                        principalTable: "ConferenceRooms",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.NoAction);
                });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var camp = await _context.Camps.Where(c => c.Moniker == moniker).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

if (camp!=null)
{
var campId=camp.Id;
 talksToBulkInsert.ForEach(i=> i.CampId=campId);

 _context.Talks.AddRange(talksToBulkInsert);
 await _context.SaveChangesAsync()
}
```

you can try this too, but is not as reliable

```
var camp = await _context.Camps.Include(i=> i.Talks)
.Where(c => c.Moniker == moniker).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

 camp.Talks.AddRange(talksToBulkInsert);
```

but at first you have to fix your data tables structures, for example

```
"conferenceRoom": {
         "id": 307,
         "campId": 34,
.....
```

How come that the child record has campId, but the parent reconrd not? you should not have any campId here at all. And there are a lot more. At first you have to create a valid db and only after this to try to add or update something.

Comment: I tried that first method you proposed, and still got the same issue.

Comment: I also tried the second method, and still get the same issue.

Comment: @BillBlair I didn' t expect any good  either since your data structure full of bugs. It will never be working properly.

Comment: Ok, so what is wrong with it? The conference room is what is making it fail, how should I change the data structure?

Comment: The json is valid, so I am not sure what is wrong with it.

Comment: Please take a look at the database schema and get back to me.

Comment: @BillBlair Remove CampId from Talks.

Comment: I can't do that, it will break other things. Is there away to just force it to no do the tracking and just insert that data? The only thing that I want it to do is to insert the conferenceroomid in the talk table, this should not be so hard - but for now, I am stuck.